# $(X\times [0,1])/\sim$ homeomorphic to $X\times S^1$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, product-space

The equivalence relation $\sim$ is given by $(x,0)\sim (x,1) \quad\forall x\in X$.

I already know that $[0, 1]/ \{0, 1\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ but have problems showing this for the given product space as I know nothing about the topological space $X$ and therefore can't use e.g. compactness.

So far, I defined $$f:X\times [0,1]\to X\times S^1,\quad f(x,y):=(x,exp(2\pi iy))$$
Therefore I get the induced map $g:(X\times [0,1])/\sim \to X\times S^1$ and I know that $g$ is a continuous bijection.
Now it remains to be shown that $g^{-1}$ is continuous, too, and that is what I'm struggling with.
Is there any theorem I can use or do I write out $g^{-1}$ to show the continuity via open sets? If so, can someone give me a starting point? I still have problems understanding the product and quotient topology.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you can show that $g$ is open or closed, then it follows that $g$ is a homeomorphism, because it’s already bijective. Do you see why it’s open? Use the product topology.

**Edit:** Note that $[0,\epsilon)\cup (1-\epsilon,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$ because its complement $[\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ is closed, hence its image, a neighbourhood of $0 \sim 1$, is also open.

Comment: Okay, I already had that statement in mind but wasn't quite sure. Via the quotient topology it suffices to show openness for $f$, which directliy implies that $g$ is open, right? And using the product topology I can reduce this to open sets on $[0,1]$ as $f$ is the identity on X.

Comment: exactly! that looks good

Comment: At first sight, considering how $f$ operates on $[0,1]$, it seems quite obvious to me that it sends open subsets to open subsets. But knowing that $[0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$ I guess I have to take a closer look at 0 and 1 or rather open sets containing these points, right?

Comment: I added an edit with a hint for your question.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I also have to admit that I'm missing some general knowledge of topology, please excuse that, but I'm doing my best to catch up. My approach would be to look at $\{\emptyset, [0,1], (a,b), [0,a), (b,1]\}$ as any open subset can be generated by these. For the first two it's clearly trivial that the image is open. In my opinion, for $(a,b)$ it's quite obvious too (am I missing something here?). I get the statement in your edit but can't put together how I can use this here, but I will think about it.

Comment: I think that my approach here wasn't correct. Is $\tilde{f}:[0,1]\to S^1, \tilde{f}(x):=exp(2\pi ix)$ really an open map? I think that the image of $[0,a)$ is not open. I guess I shouldn't reduce to considering that function but rather reduce it to $\tilde{g}:[0,1]/\{0,1\}\to S^1$, but how can I do that?

Comment: may I ask, why did you unaccept the answer?:D it is open after identifying $0,1$. Youre testing the map on the wrong set! Hint: $[0,a)$ is not open in the quotient because its complement $[a,1)$ is not closed. So its image under $exp$ doesn't have to be open! try to recall what is the definition of a quotient topology and what are the opens in consideration...?